# How to close a fixed div with javascript

Tags: hide

I have problem! I have just created a div with fixed position! I have put a close button for this div and i wanna if someone clicked on the button, the button would hide for just 24 hours, i wrote some codes to hide it but the problem is i cant set a time for it, can help me?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem! Please show us your code!

Comment: Please share you code that we can understand a bit what you have done

Comment: Code is easy it is a jQuery hiding property: $(".Button").click(function(e) {
 
 $(".Box").hide();
 
 }); I wanna tell browser to not show this .Box in 24 hours or after refreshing my site in the hours!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still interested in the solution. You can do this using cookies. Write a cookie to the users browser for the time of the click (close button click), and next time he visits your site check the value of this cookie against the current server time to see how much time has passed since he clicked the close button. 
For this to work, cookies should be enabled on your user's browser of course.